# Dynamic memory allocation in C++ class

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I am sure there is an alternative solution for this problem but I would really like to understand why my solution is not working

```
int n;
class Segtree
{

   public:
    int *s, size, h, *cl, *t; string a;
    int open, close, total;

    void init(string input,int siz)
    {
       size = siz;
       n = size;
       t = new int[size * 4];
       cl = new int[size * 4];
       s = new int[size * 4];
       a = input;
       build();
    };
}
```

I am dynamically allocating memory to arrays inside a class but I am getting some errors with memory allocation you can find it in the results [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/380/submission/18702660).
After this I allocated the memory statically. Inside the class but everytime I allocate around 10^6 size in all 3 arrays I get segfault. Note that this segfault will not occur had the array been global. What would be a good way to allocate around 10^7 size to int arrays inside a class ?

Comment: `#define boost ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0)` I don't know what to say... Your code swarms with bad practices.

Comment: That code is so bad, spare my eyes pls

Comment: @V.Kravchenko I only gave an example Sorry but this is just for Competitive programming so readability is not a prime concern

Comment: @LogicStuff Can you please elaborate I only do it for speed ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am already aware of the "Other way" to solve my problem by making all the arrays global but I still want to clear this question. Thanks.

Comment: If by 'statically' you mean on the stack then you exceeded your maximum stack size.

Comment: But I can do that globally is there a way to do it here.

Comment: Use Clion. Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+L will automatically reformat your code.